# Is there a minimum height regulation for emt conduit in a garage?

Tags: electrical, wiring

My garage doesn't have any wallboard. The EMT conduit is open and not hidden.

Is there a height minimum from the floor for running emt conduit from the switch box (normally 48") to a fluorescent light fixture over a workbench in the garage?

In short, what is the minimum distance a fluorescent light fixture or EMT conduit can be  over a workbench from the floor?

Also, should I have the emt conduit that affixes to the light fixture run toward the ceiling first (upwards) instead of parallel the way I have it directly to the outlet?

This in case if plaster board would be attached in the future. This is my second fixture being added in another location. [image: fixture]The loose garage opener door will be reattached later.

[image: total view to electrical box] Thank you again.

Comment: In addition all min height restrictions in the IRC, that I can think of off-hand apply to livable spaces.

Answer (score 1):

There is no height requirement in NEC Article 358.12, "Uses not permitted" so long as the run meets the other requirements. There is also no height requirement for task lighting over a work area. The only "standard" height for work areas I have ever heard of was 30" above a work area. I assume this is to allow you to put things on the work area and provide adequate head clearance. It would be practical to provide some sort of protection from any glass breakage such as a wraparound fixture or lamp protectors.

If you would like to review NEC requirements on fixtures go to Article 410.

Comment: Again thank you. One other thing, is there some type of a clamp requirement of 3 ft from an outlet to secure the emt? And if so can i place a 2/4 stud that would be secured between two studs behind the emt and then place a clamp over it--if there isn't a stud nearby? Or is it allowed to use a double emt bracket holder that would fastened to the conduit next to it--would this be acceptable as well to meet the 3 ft requirement?

Comment: Anyway thanks again. I will read the article.